# How can I resolve OnSucceslistener on a TabLayout Fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[This is the Database[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIEcn.png)

I am trying to populate the layout I made on a tab layout Fragment with data from a Cloud Firestore database and with the following code the error says that:

> success listener in Task cannot be applied(addOnSuccessListener
>   (com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener)
>   in Task cannot be applied
>   to
>   (anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener)
>    )

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    notebookRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new 
        OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Items items = documentSnapshot.toObject(Items.class);

                    String name1 = items.getName();
                    String company1 = items.getCompany();
                    String image1 = items.getImage();

                    name.setText(name1);
                    company.setText(company1);
                    Picasso.get()
                        .load(image1)
                        .fit()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(imageView);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Document does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
           }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add the entire error message that you get and indicate the line at which it occurs.

Comment: @AlexMamo this - addOnSuccessListener
(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<? super com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot>)
in Task cannot be applied
to
(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>)

Comment: How is `notebookRef` defined? Please also add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the DB and these are my Firebase Reference - private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("Phones");

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> addOnSuccessListener (com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener) in Task cannot be applied to (anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener)

Because you are using `DocumentSnapshot` instead of using a `QuerySnapshot`. To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference phonesRef = rootRef.collection("Phones");
phonesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Items items = document.toObject(Items.class);

                String name1 = items.getName();
                String company1 = items.getCompany();
                String image1 = items.getImage();

                name.setText(name1);
                company.setText(company1);
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(image1)
                        .fit()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(imageView);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now it will work since we are using `QuerySnapshot` and **not** the `DocumentSnapshot` to get the `Item` objects.

Comment: Hey Alex take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302823/how-do-i-add-all-items-from-cloud-firestore-being-displayed-with-recycler-firest

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.